# are であり, であって, and で interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

are であり, であって, and で interchangeable?

Example:

> きれいで可愛い女子

> きれいであり可愛い女子

> きれいであって可愛い女子

Comment: The first is normal て form for na-adjectives, the second is the stem of である and the third is てform for である. I'm not really sure what the difference is, but である is more formal or official style I believe

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically yes in the sense that all the expressions will be understood as the same thing (a girl who is beautiful and pretty). But the last two are not natural.

As mentioned in the comment, the first one is 2 adjectives + noun while the others are きれい +  continuative form of である + adjective + noun so that the last two are sort of unbalanced (They may correspond to something like *a pretty girl who is beautiful*, which should be grammatically correct but unnatural).